# Angular - Create a property on a property

Tags: angular

How do I fix the following error on my view:

```
ERROR in src/app/sermon/sermon.component.html(14,46): : Property 'sessionEnum' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
```

Code for the view:

```
<div class="product-details text">
  <ul class="info-list">
    <li><span>Session : </span> {{ sermon?.sermonSession?.sessionEnum }}</li>
    <li><span>Recorded : </span> {{ sermon.date }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I take it I need to create that property on sermonSession:

```
export namespace SermonModule {

  export interface Serializable<T> {
    deserialize(input: Object): T;
  }

  export class Sermon implements Serializable<Sermon> {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    fileName: string;
    speaker: string;
    description: string;
    tags: string[];
    date: string;
    sermonSession: string[];

    deserialize(input) {
      this.id = input.id;
      this.name = input.name;
      this.fileName = input.fileName;
      this.speaker = input.speaker;
      this.description = input.description;
      this.tags = input.tags;
      this.date = input.date;
      this.sermonSession = input.sermonSession;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Question is... how do I create a property on a property?

My code for the component is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943120/angular-404-not-found-when-loading-async-data-from-endpoint).

Comment: What does your `input` that is passed to `deserialize`?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943120/angular-404-not-found-when-loading-async-data-from-endpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use it like this: sermon?.sermonSession?.sessionEnum you have to make it object, not an array.

```
let sermonSession = { sessionEnum: 'some string'};
```

But if you pass an array of object you can do it like:

```
sermon.sermonSession[0].sessionEnum
```

all depend on your implementation.

How object model will looks:

```
export namespace SermonModule {

  export interface Serializable<T> {
    deserialize(input: Object): T;
  }

  export class Sermon implements Serializable<Sermon> {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    fileName: string;
    speaker: string;
    description: string;
    tags: string[];
    date: string;
    sermonSession: object;

    deserialize(input) {
      this.id = input.id;
      this.name = input.name;
      this.fileName = input.fileName;
      this.speaker = input.speaker;
      this.description = input.description;
      this.tags = input.tags;
      this.date = input.date;
      this.sermonSession = input.sermonSession;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How would the data model look like then?

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to create object like

```
this.sermon={
   ...
   sermonSession: {
     ...,
     sessionEnum:"value"
   }
}
```

check your object nesting, whether its similar to this format or not.